# Why my angular ngx-mat-datetime-picker's and mat-datepicker's css clash if they are on the same page?

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, datetimepicker

I have two input fields in the same form under each other. One is an ngx-mat-datetime-picker and the other one is a mat-datepicker.
Separately they work properly, but if I open them for the second time the one I opened for the first time opens with a messed up css.

code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Schlusstag</mat-label>
            <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="schlusstag" placeholder="schlusstag"
                [formControl]="fc.schlusstag" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="schlusstag"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #schlusstag></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Valuta</mat-label>
            <input matInput [formControl]="fc.valuta" placeholder="Valuta" maxlength="10" [matDatepicker]="valuta"
                autocomplete="off" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="valuta"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #valuta></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

usecase 1:
I open the ngx-mat-datetime-picker select a date then click apply. Then I open the mat-datepicker select a time. Everything works fine until this point. Then I open ngx-mat-datetime-picker and it looks like this:
[image: Messed up CSS on ngx-mat-datetime-picker]

usecase 2:
I open the mat-datepicker select a value then open the ngx-mat-datetime-picker and select a value. After I open the mat-datepicker and then it's CSS is messed up:
[image: Messed up CSS on mat-datepicker].

I have no errors in the console and don't know why do they mess up each others CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the use of @angular/material@^16, the CSS rules below are the contents of four stylesheets that are pushed onto globalThis.document.styleSheets when the first  component of a host Angular app is instantiated. (That typically occurs after the first click of a  component.)

Apparently, an  component relies on one or more of these rules for proper presentation. The stylesheets pushed onto globalThis.document.styleSheets with the first instantiation of an  component omit copies or equivalents of those rules, whichever ones they are. That's the origin of this issue.

Copying these rules into a global stylesheet of the host Angular app is a workaround for this bug.

````
.mat-datepicker-toggle {
    pointer-events: auto;
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-toggle-icon-color);
}

.mat-datepicker-toggle-active {
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-toggle-active-state-icon-color);
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-datepicker-toggle-default-icon {
    color: canvastext;
}

.mat-datepicker-content {
    box-shadow:
        rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 0 2px 4px -1px,
        rgb(0 0 0 / 14%) 0 4px 5px 0,
        rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0 1px 10px 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-container-background-color);
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-container-text-color);
}

.mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar {
    width: 296px;
    height: 354px;
}

.mat-datepicker-content
    .mat-datepicker-content-container-with-custom-header
    .mat-calendar {
    height: auto;
}

.mat-datepicker-content .mat-datepicker-close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.ng-animating .mat-datepicker-content .mat-datepicker-close-button {
    display: none;
}

.mat-datepicker-content-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.mat-datepicker-content-touch {
    box-shadow:
        rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 0 11px 15px -7px,
        rgb(0 0 0 / 14%) 0 24px 38px 3px,
        rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0 9px 46px 8px;
    display: block;
    max-height: 80vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

.mat-datepicker-content-touch .mat-datepicker-content-container {
    min-height: 312px;
    max-height: 788px;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 750px;
}

.mat-datepicker-content-touch .mat-calendar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    .mat-datepicker-content-touch .mat-datepicker-content-container {
        width: 64vh;
        height: 80vh;
    }
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    .mat-datepicker-content-touch .mat-datepicker-content-container {
        width: 80vw;
        height: 100vw;
    }

    .mat-datepicker-content-touch
        .mat-datepicker-content-container-with-actions {
        height: 115vw;
    }
}

.mat-calendar {
    display: block;
    font-family: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-text-font);
    font-size: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-text-size);
}

.mat-calendar-header {
    padding: 8px 8px 0;
}

.mat-calendar-content {
    padding: 0 8px 8px;
    outline: none;
}

.mat-calendar-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5% calc(4.71429% - 16px);
}

.mat-calendar-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.mat-calendar-period-button {
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0 8px;
    font-size: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-period-button-text-size);
    font-weight: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-period-button-text-weight);
}

.mat-calendar-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-period-button-icon-color);
}

.mat-calendar-arrow.mat-calendar-invert {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-arrow {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-arrow {
    fill: canvastext;
}

.mat-calendar-previous-button,
.mat-calendar-next-button {
    position: relative;
}

.mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar-previous-button,
.mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar-next-button {
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-navigation-button-icon-color);
}

.mat-calendar-previous-button::after,
.mat-calendar-next-button::after {
    inset: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    margin: 15.5px;
    border-width: 2px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: currentColor;
    border-image: initial;
}

[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-previous-button,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-next-button {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.mat-calendar-previous-button::after {
    border-left-width: 2px;
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.mat-calendar-next-button::after {
    border-right-width: 2px;
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(45deg);
}

.mat-calendar-table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.mat-calendar-table-header th {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-header-text-color);
    font-size: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-header-text-size);
    font-weight: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-header-text-weight);
}

.mat-calendar-table-header-divider {
    position: relative;
    height: 1px;
}

.mat-calendar-table-header-divider::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    height: 1px;
    background: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-header-divider-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell-content::before {
    margin: calc(calc(var(--mat-focus-indicator-border-width, 3px) + 3px) * -1);
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell:focus .mat-focus-indicator::before {
    content: '';
}

.mat-calendar-hidden-label {
    display: none;
}

.mat-calendar-body {
    min-width: 224px;
}

.mat-calendar-body-today:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-selected,
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical
    ) {
    border-color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-today-outline-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-label {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4.71429%;
    padding-right: 4.71429%;
    font-size: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-body-label-text-size);
    font-weight: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-body-label-text-weight);
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-body-label-text-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-hidden-label {
    display: none;
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell {
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell::before,
.mat-calendar-body-cell::after,
.mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

.mat-calendar-body-range-start:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range
    )::before,
.mat-calendar-body-range-start::after,
.mat-calendar-body-comparison-start:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-start
    )::before,
.mat-calendar-body-comparison-start::after,
.mat-calendar-body-preview-start .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    left: 5%;
    width: 95%;
    border-top-left-radius: 999px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 999px;
}

[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-range-start:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range
    )::before,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-range-start::after,
[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-start:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-start
    )::before,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-comparison-start::after,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-preview-start .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 999px 999px 0;
}

.mat-calendar-body-range-end:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range
    )::before,
.mat-calendar-body-range-end::after,
.mat-calendar-body-comparison-end:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-end
    )::before,
.mat-calendar-body-comparison-end::after,
.mat-calendar-body-preview-end .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    width: 95%;
    border-top-right-radius: 999px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 999px;
}

[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-range-end:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range
    )::before,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-range-end::after,
[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-end:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-end
    )::before,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-comparison-end::after,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-preview-end .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    left: 5%;
    border-radius: 999px 0 0 999px;
}

[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-start.mat-calendar-body-range-end::after,
[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-end.mat-calendar-body-range-start::after {
    width: 95%;
    border-top-right-radius: 999px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 999px;
}

.mat-calendar-body-comparison-start.mat-calendar-body-range-end::after,
[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-start.mat-calendar-body-range-end::after,
.mat-calendar-body-comparison-end.mat-calendar-body-range-start::after,
[dir='rtl']
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-end.mat-calendar-body-range-start::after {
    width: 90%;
}

.mat-calendar-body-in-preview {
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-preview-state-outline-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-in-preview .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    border-top: 1px dashed;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}

.mat-calendar-body-preview-start .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    border-left: 1px dashed;
}

[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-preview-start .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 1px dashed;
}

.mat-calendar-body-preview-end .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    border-right: 1px dashed;
}

[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-preview-end .mat-calendar-body-cell-preview {
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 1px dashed;
}

.mat-calendar-body-disabled {
    cursor: default;
}

.mat-calendar-body-disabled
    > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-selected,
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical
    ) {
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-disabled-state-text-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-disabled
    > .mat-calendar-body-today:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-selected,
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical
    ) {
    border-color: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-today-disabled-state-outline-color
    );
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    line-height: 1;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 999px;
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-text-color);
    border-color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-outline-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-cell-content.mat-focus-indicator {
    position: absolute;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
    border: none;
}

.cdk-keyboard-focused
    .mat-calendar-body-active
    > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-selected,
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical
    ),
.cdk-program-focused
    .mat-calendar-body-active
    > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(
        .mat-calendar-body-selected,
        .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical
    ) {
    background-color: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-focus-state-background-color
    );
}
@media (hover: hover) {
    .mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled):hover
        > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(
            .mat-calendar-body-selected,
            .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical
        ) {
        background-color: var(
            --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-hover-state-background-color
        );
    }
}

.mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background-color: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-selected-state-background-color
    );
    color: var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-selected-state-text-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-disabled > .mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background-color: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-selected-disabled-state-background-color
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-selected.mat-calendar-body-today {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px
        var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-today-selected-state-outline-color);
}

.mat-calendar-body-in-range::before {
    background: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-range-state-background-color
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical,
.mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range::before {
    background: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-comparison-range-state-background-color
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical,
.mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range::before {
    background: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-comparison-range-state-background-color
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-start::before,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-end::before {
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-range-state-background-color) 50%,
        var(
                --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-comparison-range-state-background-color
            )
            50%
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-end::before,
[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-start::before {
    background: linear-gradient(
        to left,
        var(--mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-range-state-background-color) 50%,
        var(
                --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-comparison-range-state-background-color
            )
            50%
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-in-range > .mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical,
.mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range.mat-calendar-body-in-range::after {
    background: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-overlap-range-state-background-color
    );
}

.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical.mat-calendar-body-selected,
.mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range > .mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background: var(
        --mat-datepicker-calendar-date-in-overlap-range-selected-state-background-color
    );
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-datepicker-popup:not(:empty),
.cdk-high-contrast-active
    .mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-in-range)
    .mat-calendar-body-selected {
    outline: solid 1px;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-today {
    outline: dotted 1px;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-cell::before,
.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-cell::after,
.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background: none;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-in-range::before,
.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-start::before,
.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-comparison-bridge-end::before {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-range-start::before {
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

[dir='rtl'] .cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-range-start::before {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-range-end::before {
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

[dir='rtl'] .cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-range-end::before {
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-in-comparison-range::before {
    border-top: 1px dashed;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-comparison-start::before {
    border-left: 1px dashed;
}

[dir='rtl']
    .cdk-high-contrast-active
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-start::before {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 1px dashed;
}

.cdk-high-contrast-active .mat-calendar-body-comparison-end::before {
    border-right: 1px dashed;
}

[dir='rtl']
    .cdk-high-contrast-active
    .mat-calendar-body-comparison-end::before {
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 1px dashed;
}

[dir='rtl'] .mat-calendar-body-label {
    text-align: right;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this issue in an `Angular 14` project with `@angular-material-components/datetime-picker` v8

Looking at the [github issue](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/269), others have suggested workarounds. I used the following style and it appears to have fixed the issue for me:

```css
mat-calendar .mat-calendar-body-cell {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because both of your datepickers will bring it own CSS, and the class may be the same. The one that merge later will override the first one. You have several options:

1. Use only one lib for datepicker
2. Don't use two different datepickers in the same component
3. Add a specific classe for your component that use datepicker and use `::ng-deep your-class datepicker-class-is-override` to rewrite the CSS for the overriden class

It is better to use only one datepicker in your entire application, it helps to have the trouble like this